# Query in MongoDB that search is true; query syntax troubles

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

This is probably an embarrassing question but I'm attempting to render a user search based on both location searching & date. Our profile object is structed as follows;

```
availability: {
    monday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    tuesday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    wednesday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    thursday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    friday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    saturday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    sunday: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  }
```

Here is my controller;

```
exports.findUsersByDay = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const search = req.params.search;

  try {
    const profileList = await Profile.find({
      availability: { $in: search }
    });

    if (profileList.length > 0) {
      return res.status(200).json({ profiles: profileList });
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "No Profiles Found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
})
```

How Can I query whether the profile object has one of the dates (or multiple if passed down as an array) to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dynamic query for this.
Get all the days you wand and use it along with [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) :

```
let findQuery = { $and : [ ]};
let search = ['monday','thursday']; search.forEach((a)=>{
  let aName = `availability.${a}` 
findQuery['$and'].push({
[aName] : true
})});

const profileList = await Profile.find(findQuery);
```

I think something similar could be done using [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) too, but performance will take a hit.

Comment: Is this searching within the availability field object? The issue I still seem to be having is that it's not searching within that field.

Comment: It's returning profiles with all false, default values but true in other fields

Comment: I forgot to add the availability string in front. Check edited answer?